# understanding the $.extend in modal.js and its real world implications

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

hey guys have a look at the below line of code in modal.js :

```
var option  = $target.data('ga.modal') ? 'toggle' :
    $.extend({ remote: !/#/.test(href) && href }, $target.data(), $this.data())
```

**1st Difficulty**

now i don't quite undertsand the 1st parameter being passed to $.extend i.e.  `remote: !/#/.test(href) && href`

also , whie using bootstrap modal.js , `option` = `toggle` because `$target.data('bs.modal')` never evalutes to false .

**2nd difficulty**

does anybody know when `$target.data('bs.modal')` evalutes to false , i mean in real world usage ??

line of difficulty can be found on [git too](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L324) .

**EDIT ::** can somebody just solve my 1st difficulty , i'll try finding out the 2nd question and posting an answer .

Thank you.

Comment: `!/#/.test(href) && href` evaluates to `false` when `href` contains no `#` and to `href` otherwise. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test for details

Comment: @Bergi , i am guessing the !is the not operator and the condition `!/#/.test(href)` is checking that there is no # inside the href attribute specified . ?? am i right ?

Comment: [yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_.28.21.29)